# How can I edit display settings of a screen connected via remote desktop protocol (RDP) in ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: 22.04, rdp, ipad

I was able of setting up an iPad as a second screen in Mirror mode, by following [this tutorial](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/06/use-ipad-as-second-monitor-ubuntu-22-04). It uses the new Remote desktop feature, inside Settings -> Sharing -> Remote Desktop. I can visualize my desktop on my iPad by connecting through a remote desktop client (in my case it is Microsoft Remote Desktop for Mobile). But when I try to change the settings of my new second virtual screen, I do not find it in the Displays menu, in the Settings app on Ubuntu.

I already tried doing `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt upgrade`.

Can someone point me in the right direction to solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: Usually the display setting of the remote screen is in the XRDP client. In your case, the client is the "Microsoft Remote Desktop for Mobile" app.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I tried following this tutorial and at first I had similar luck to you, although in my case the connection cease immediately after trying to connect. Then this morning i finally get it to work. this are some of the things that you may have wrong (at least things i did wrong).
Make sure you are in Gnome 42 or later, you will find it on the settings/ about

I also installed gnome remote desktop manually but I'm not sure if it is necessary, run:

$ sudo apt-get -y install gnome-remote-desktop

If you try using xrdp de-install it may by figthing for your port 3389
you may also want an exception of firewall for your tablet device

$ sudo ufw allow from (ipad ip) to any port 3389

Make sure you are using rdp and not the VNC protocol, is the checked box in your remote desktop settings

in addition you need use wayland not xorg for log in on ubuntu, at least in my case, it's a petty because apps like teams cannot screen share using wayland, at least to my knowledge

of course you need to run

$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.remote-desktop.rdp screen-share-mode extend

and the last thing that i did that finally make this feature work for my is running:

$ systemctl --user restart gnome-remote-desktop.service

I hope it helps, I know i'm a bit late, but at least if someone like my encounters similar user they'll have some path to follow